# Reading a JSON stream with boost::asio, get full string?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am reading a TCP stream using boost. The stream is in this format:

```
"{\"animationValues\":{\"mouth_rightMouth_stretch\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_leftMouth_narrow\":0.00000000000000000,\"mouth_up\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_leftMouth_stretch\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_rightMouth_narrow\":0.00000000000000000,\"mouth_down\":0.00000000000000000,\"mouth_upperLip_left_up\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_upperLip_right_up\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_lowerLip_left_down\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_lowerLip_right_down\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_leftMouth_frown\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_rightMouth_frown\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_leftMouth_smile\":0.00000000000000000,\"mouth_rightMouth_smile\":0.00000000000000000,\"eyes_lookRight\":0.0000000000000000,\"eyes_lookLeft\":0.00000000000000000,\"eyes_lookDown\":0.0000000000000000,\"eyes_lookUp\":0.00000000000000000,\"eyes_leftEye_blink\":0.00000000000000000,\"eyes_rightEye_blink\":0.00000000000000000,\"eyes_leftEye_wide\":0.0000000000000000,\"eyes_rightEye_wide\":0.0000000000000000,\"brows_leftBrow_up\":0.0000000000000000,\"brows_leftBrow_down\":0.00000000000000000,\"brows_rightBrow_up\":0.0000000000000000,\"brows_rightBrow_down\":0.00000000000000000,\"brows_midBrows_up\":0.0000000000000000,\"brows_midBrows_down\":0.00000000000000000,\"jaw_open\":0.0000000000000000,\"jaw_left\":0.0000000000000000,\"jaw_right\":0.00000000000000000,\"mouth_phoneme_oo\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_right\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_left\":0.00000000000000000,\"mouth_phoneme_mbp\":0.0000000000000000,\"mouth_phoneme_ch\":0.0000000000000000},\"headRot\":[0.0,0.0, 0.0]}";
```

I am trying to read this and parse each string as it comes in. So what I need to do is split the stream into sections that look like the above. I have tried:

```
  boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::read_until(sock, buffer, "]}"", error);
    std::istream str(&buffer);
```

but this only gives me half of the string that I need. I have tried:

```
boost::array<char, 2046> buf; 
size_t len = sock.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error); 
std::string data(buf.begin(), buf.end());
```

but this gives me even less. How can I read one section of the stream at a time? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked for errors?

Comment: The code compiles, and runs. It connects to the socket and streams data. But it is only ever a section of the string at a time, not the entire thing.

Comment: I meant, have you checked the value of `error`. Which would report errors.

Comment: thank you for your replies. when I break on `boost::system::error_code error;`, the m_val is 0. I assume this means no error.

Comment: It does. You can simply test it in code `if (error) std::cout << "Error: " << error.message() << "\n";`

Comment: ok great! I am error free. How can i get my whole message though? Is `read_until` the best option here?

Comment: Unrelated, but there are also other libraries that directly parse JSON strings/files for you. For example [nlohmann.github.io/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

Comment: Thank you! i am using rapidJson, but just need to feed it the whole message, which I am having trouble with...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd use read_until, or any of the `boost::asio::read_*` family, because they do composed read operations (in constract with `read_some`).

Here's a POC of this working:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7aa2a4bdc698411)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using ip::tcp;

    io_service io;
    tcp::acceptor a(io, { {}, 6768 });
    a.listen(5);

    tcp::socket s(io);
    a.accept(s);

    streambuf sb;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    read_until(s, sb, "]}", ec);

    std::cout << "Response: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    std::cout << "'" << &sb << "'\n";
}
```

As you can see, when sending

```
{"animationValues": {"mouth_rightMouth_stretch": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_narrow": 0,"mouth_up": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_stretch": 0,"mouth_rightMouth_narrow": 0,"mouth_down": 0,"mouth_upperLip_left_up": 0,"mouth_upperLip_right_up": 0,"mouth_lowerLip_left_down": 0,"mouth_lowerLip_right_down": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_frown": 0,"mouth_rightMouth_frown": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_smile": 0,"mouth_rightMouth_smile": 0,"eyes_lookRight": 0,"eyes_lookLeft": 0,"eyes_lookDown": 0,"eyes_lookUp": 0,"eyes_leftEye_blink": 0,"eyes_rightEye_blink": 0,"eyes_leftEye_wide": 0,"eyes_rightEye_wide": 0,"brows_leftBrow_up": 0,"brows_leftBrow_down": 0,"brows_rightBrow_up": 0,"brows_rightBrow_down": 0,"brows_midBrows_up": 0,"brows_midBrows_down": 0,"jaw_open": 0,"jaw_left": 0,"jaw_right": 0,"mouth_phoneme_oo": 0,"mouth_right": 0,"mouth_left": 0,"mouth_phoneme_mbp": 0,"mouth_phoneme_ch": 0},"headRot": [0, 0, 0]}
{"animationValues": {"mouth_rightMouth_stretch": 1,"mouth_leftMouth_narrow": 1,"mouth_up": 1,"mouth_leftMouth_stretch": 1,"mouth_rightMouth_narrow": 1,"mouth_down": 1,"mouth_upperLip_left_up": 1,"mouth_upperLip_right_up": 1,"mouth_lowerLip_left_down": 1,"mouth_lowerLip_right_down": 1,"mouth_leftMouth_frown": 1,"mouth_rightMouth_frown": 1,"mouth_leftMouth_smile": 1,"mouth_rightMouth_smile": 1,"eyes_lookRight": 1,"eyes_lookLeft": 1,"eyes_lookDown": 1,"eyes_lookUp": 1,"eyes_leftEye_blink": 1,"eyes_rightEye_blink": 1,"eyes_leftEye_wide": 1,"eyes_rightEye_wide": 1,"brows_leftBrow_up": 1,"brows_leftBrow_down": 1,"brows_rightBrow_up": 1,"brows_rightBrow_down": 1,"brows_midBrows_up": 1,"brows_midBrows_down": 1,"jaw_open": 1,"jaw_left": 1,"jaw_right": 1,"mouth_phoneme_oo": 1,"mouth_right": 1,"mouth_left": 1,"mouth_phoneme_mbp": 1,"mouth_phoneme_ch": 1},"headRot": [1, 1, 1]}
{"animationValues": {"mouth_rightMouth_stretch": 2,"mouth_leftMouth_narrow": 2,"mouth_up": 2,"mouth_leftMouth_stretch": 2,"mouth_rightMouth_narrow": 2,"mouth_down": 2,"mouth_upperLip_left_up": 2,"mouth_upperLip_right_up": 2,"mouth_lowerLip_left_down": 2,"mouth_lowerLip_right_down": 2,"mouth_leftMouth_frown": 2,"mouth_rightMouth_frown": 2,"mouth_leftMouth_smile": 2,"mouth_rightMouth_smile": 2,"eyes_lookRight": 2,"eyes_lookLeft": 2,"eyes_lookDown": 2,"eyes_lookUp": 2,"eyes_leftEye_blink": 2,"eyes_rightEye_blink": 2,"eyes_leftEye_wide": 2,"eyes_rightEye_wide": 2,"brows_leftBrow_up": 2,"brows_leftBrow_down": 2,"brows_rightBrow_up": 2,"brows_rightBrow_down": 2,"brows_midBrows_up": 2,"brows_midBrows_down": 2,"jaw_open": 2,"jaw_left": 2,"jaw_right": 2,"mouth_phoneme_oo": 2,"mouth_right": 2,"mouth_left": 2,"mouth_phoneme_mbp": 2,"mouth_phoneme_ch": 2},"headRot": [2, 2, 2]}
```

It prints:

```
Response: Success
'{"animationValues": {"mouth_rightMouth_stretch": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_narrow": 0,"mouth_up": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_stretch": 0,"mouth_rightMouth_narrow": 0,"mouth_down": 0,"mouth_upperLip_left_up": 0,"mouth_upperLip_right_up": 0,"mouth_lowerLip_left_down": 0,"mouth_lowerLip_right_down": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_frown": 0,"mouth_rightMouth_frown": 0,"mouth_leftMouth_smile": 0,"mouth_rightMouth_smile": 0,"eyes_lookRight": 0,"eyes_lookLeft": 0,"eyes_lookDown": 0,"eyes_lookUp": 0,"eyes_leftEye_blink": 0,"eyes_rightEye_blink": 0,"eyes_leftEye_wide": 0,"eyes_rightEye_wide": 0,"brows_leftBrow_up": 0,"brows_leftBrow_down": 0,"brows_rightBrow_up": 0,"brows_rightBrow_down": 0,"brows_midBrows_up": 0,"brows_midBrows_down": 0,"jaw_open": 0,"jaw_left": 0,"jaw_right": 0,"mouth_phoneme_oo": 0,"mouth_right": 0,"mouth_left": 0,"mouth_phoneme_mbp": 0,"mouth_phoneme_ch": 0},"headRot": [0, 0, 0]}
{"animationValues": {"mouth_rightMouth_stretch": 1,"mouth_leftMouth_narrow": 1,"mouth_up": 1,"mouth_leftMouth_stretch": 1,"mouth_rightMouth_narrow'
```

Things to be aware of:

1. make sure the formatting is actually such that `]}` occurs. This means that pretty-printed json is not recognized:

   ```
           "mouth_phoneme_mbp": 2,
           "mouth_phoneme_ch": 2
       },
       "headRot": [2, 2, 2]
   }
   ```
2. also make sure you are aware of the fact that `read_until` may return a buffer that contains *more* data (it will return as soon as the delimiter is satisfied, but more data may have been read)